# Parsing Specific Portion of HTML Block

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I'm pulling an HTML block from a site that looks something like this

```
<strong>Suggested use:</strong> 
"This is the suggested use text"
<br><br>
<strong>Warning:</strong> 
"This is the warning text"
```

I'm trying to pull just the value for either the text under the suggested use  block and the text under the warning  block and store them in 2 separate fields. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to parse this specifically. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? and what language or tool is it?

Comment: could you add the bigger part of your html document? I want to see the parent(s) node of this part of your document

Answer (score -1):

I see you tagged this as regex so:

```
$str  = '<strong>Suggested use:</strong> "This is the suggested us text" <br><br> <strong>Warning:</strong> "This is the warning text"';

if (preg_match_all('/"([^"]+)"/', $str, $m)) 
    print_r($m[0]);
```

**Output:** `Array ( [0] => "This is the suggested use text" [1] => "This is the warning text" )`

Also if you don't want the quotes use: print_r($m[1]);

**EDIT:** I thought I was in the PHP section so presumed it was php regex, some clarification would be great.